# SQL con el dato de un TextBox WebForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

como dice el titulo, no puedo hacer que mi caja de texto pueda pasar como variable a un query SQL.

Lo que quiero hacer es que en un campo de Texto, escribir algo, y dentro del boton "BUSCAR" haya un query que busque dicho texto en una determinada tabla.

Mi codigo ASPX es el siguiente:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Ventas/credito-wizard.Master"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="form-group">
<label>DNI</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="DNI" runat="server" class="form-control" name="DNI" required="true" placeholder="DNI del Cliente" value="" aria-describedby="address1-error"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="revisarDNI" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" OnClick="Click1_OnClick" >Revisar DNI</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="DNI" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="El campo de DNI es obligatorio." />
<span class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa el DNI del cliente.</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Nombres</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="Nombres" runat="server" class="form-control" name="nombre" Enabled="false" required="true" placeholder="Nombres" value="" aria-describedby="address1-error"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Nombres" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="El campo de Contacto de Nombres es obligatorio." />
<span class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa los nombres del cliente.</span>
</div>
```

mi codigo ASPX.CS:

```
private readonly string str = "Mi cadena de DB";

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatosSQL();
        }

        protected void DatosSQL()
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //DNI
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE NumeroDocumento = '" + this.DNI.Text + "'", con);
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        Nombres.Text = myReader[3].ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Click1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatosSQL();
}
```

El problema es que cuando le doy click en el boton, no me muestra nada, pero si coloco dentro del query un numero correcto, se muestra el nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quita del método `DatosSQL()`** el condicional **`if (!Page.IsPostBack) { ... }`**, ya que estás realizando un **postback** desde el **Click** del botón y por esa razón no entra en el **`using ( ... )`**.

También estás repitiendo la llamada al método `DatosSQL()` desde **dos sitios diferentes**, yo lo dejaría solamente en el `protected void Click1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }`.

Comment: Pensé que se me habia pasado lo del boton, pero esta ahi. `<asp:LinkButton ID="revisarDNI" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" OnClick="Click1_OnClick" >Revisar DNI</asp:LinkButton>`
Voy a intentar con lo que me dices.

Comment: Tienes razón no lo había visto, ya corregí el comentario. Gracias.

Comment: Tenias razón, ya me funciono el codigo, muchas gracias !